# C# - Simple SubMenu

Tags: c#, razor

Im trying to make a simple drop down list on Gaming saying PC.

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>                             
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="@Html.ActionLink("Gaming", "Gaming", "Gaming")" data-toggle="dropdown">Gaming <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                       <li>@Html.ActionLink("PC", "Gaming","Gaming")</li>                    
                    </ul>
                </li>                                                         
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
```

**The program crashes:**

http://localhost:9949/%3Ca%20href=

Server Error in '/' Application.

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +561
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +54

Any idea why?

Comment: What does the link render *as*?

Comment: What? I just want to click Gaming and open a submenu with PC inside

Comment: And I just want to clarify the issue.  Sometimes we do that on SO.  Can you respond to my query?  What HTML does your Razor code render into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not suppose to put `@Html.ActionLink` inside `href` attribute of *Gaming* item, use `@Url.Action` instead.

`@Html.ActionLink` create the whole `a` tag, while you just need the URL to the proper action in controller, and this is what `@Url.Action` is used for.

The result of `@Html.ActionLink("Name", "action", "controller")` is `<a href="/controller/action">Name</a>`.

The result of `@Url.Action("action", controller")` is just URL string `'/controller/action'`.

Comment: What?  Both answers explain why.  My answer elaborates on why this is a problem.  Did you read my answer?  What do you not understand?

Comment: `@Html` helper is mostly for generating parts of the view, e.g. `@Html.ActionLink` generates `<a ...></a>` tags. `@Url.Action` simply generates a url for the action you expect. I extended my answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I made the mistake of using `@Html.Action`, it should have been `@Url.Action`.  I'll leave my answer up, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="@Html.ActionLink("Gaming", "Gaming", "Gaming")" data-toggle="dropdown">Gaming <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

`Html.ActionLink` renders as an `<a>` tag.  You are attempting to set that tag as an `href` value.  That clearly won't work, as an element isn't a valid URL.  In effect, you are getting code that looks like:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" 
   role="button" 
   aria-expanded="false" 
   href="<a href=".....">blah</a>" 
   data-toggle="dropdown">Gaming <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

That's not a valid `href`.  You should use [`@Html.Action(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx) instead.  That generates just the URL.

Comment: What do I put inside href then?

Comment: I told you at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: `@Html.Action` invokes the controller action, as described in linked MSDN documentation, it does not produce the URL, `@Url.Action` does.

Comment: @Amy I tried to make it work but now When I click Gaming/PC it goes to Gaming instead of Gaming/PC

Comment: @xDDD if you can't or won't provide us with the rendered HTML, I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: @tdragon yeah, its been a while since I used MVC.  bad memory.  I'll leave this up, as it does explain what the problem is.